# Element wise function on pycuda::complex array

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I want to run a function on a large, 2D complex array (eventually 2**12x2**12 datapoints). However, pycuda does not work as expected. The ElementWise function doesn't work at 2d arrays, so I used the SourceModule function with block sizes.

The problem is now that the C code on the GPU does not give the same result as the numpy calculation on the CPU. Very large and strange numbers are resulting.

I'm using the following code. What's going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#https://github.com/lebedov/scikits.cuda/blob/master/demos/indexing_2d_demo.py
"""
Demonstrates how to access 2D arrays within a PyCUDA kernel in a
numpy-consistent manner.
"""

from string import Template
import pycuda
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Set size
A = 2**3
B = 2**3
N = A*B
x_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: (1.+x)*np.exp(1.j*y*np.pi/10), (A,B)) )
y_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: 1.*x, (A,B)).astype(
                                x_gpu.dtype)) 
d_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.zeros_like(x_gpu.get()))#.astype(np.float32))

func_mod_template = Template("""
// Macro for converting subscripts to linear index:
#define INDEX(a, b) a*${B}+b
#include <pycuda-complex.hpp>

//__global__ void func(double *d,double *x,double *y, unsigned int N) {
__global__ void func(pycuda::complex<float> *d,pycuda::complex<float> *x,
                     pycuda::complex<float> *y)
{
    // Obtain the linear index corresponding to the current thread:     
    // unsigned int idx =  blockIdx.y*blockDim.y*gridDim.x + 
                        blockIdx.x*blockDim.x*gridDim.y +threadIdx.x+threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int block_num        = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;              
    unsigned int thread_num       = threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;           
    unsigned int threads_in_block = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;                          
    unsigned int idx              =  (threads_in_block * block_num + thread_num);

    // Convert the linear index to subscripts:
    unsigned int a = idx/${B};
    unsigned int b = idx%${B};

    // Use the subscripts to access the array:
    // d[INDEX(a,b)] = x[INDEX(a,b)]+y[INDEX(a,b)];
    pycuda::complex<float> j(0,arg(x[idx]));
    pycuda::complex<float> i(abs(x[idx]),0);
    d[idx] = i * exp(j);
}
""")

max_threads_per_block = pycuda.autoinit.device.get_attribute(pycuda._driver.device_attribute.MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK)
max_block_dim = (pycuda.autoinit.device.get_attribute(pycuda._driver.device_attribute.MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X),
                 pycuda.autoinit.device.get_attribute(pycuda._driver.device_attribute.MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Y),
                 pycuda.autoinit.device.get_attribute(pycuda._driver.device_attribute.MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Z))
max_grid_dim = (pycuda.autoinit.device.get_attribute(pycuda._driver.device_attribute.MAX_GRID_DIM_X),
                pycuda.autoinit.device.get_attribute(pycuda._driver.device_attribute.MAX_GRID_DIM_Y),
                pycuda.autoinit.device.get_attribute(pycuda._driver.device_attribute.MAX_GRID_DIM_Z))
max_blocks_per_grid = max(max_grid_dim)
block_dim = max_block_dim
block_dim = (max_block_dim[0],1,1)
grid_dim = (int(np.ceil(1.*x_gpu.shape[0]/block_dim[0])),
            int(np.ceil(1.*x_gpu.shape[1]/block_dim[1])))
print block_dim,grid_dim, N

func_mod = \
         SourceModule(func_mod_template.substitute(max_threads_per_block=max_threads_per_block,
                                                   max_blocks_per_grid=max_blocks_per_grid,
                                                   A=A, B=B))
func = func_mod.get_function('func')
func(d_gpu,x_gpu,y_gpu,
     block=block_dim,
    grid=grid_dim)

print d_gpu.get()/x_gpu.get()
#print 'Success status: ', np.allclose(x_np, x_gpu.get())
plt.imshow((d_gpu.get()/x_gpu.get()).real)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: i am not an expert, but i would suggest being more explicit with types.  make sure that the numpy data array is float32 (you can explicitly give types for numpy arrays), say, and then use the same in the kernel.

Comment: I have just checked the code and x_gpu is indeed created with dtype complex128 (default). Casting it to complex64 seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Per @Bogdan, np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: (1.+x)*np.exp(1.j*y*np.pi/10), (A,B)).astype(np.complex64) should do the trick. Always, always knowing what type and what order (C vs Fortran) the data you're passing into the device will make your stay in Hotel PyCUDA more enjoyable.

Comment: Please post as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

As an actual answer: changing the `x_gpu` line to

```
x_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.fromfunction(
    lambda x,y: (1.+x)*np.exp(1.j*y*np.pi/10), (A,B)).astype(np.complex64) )
```

seems to fix the problem. Also, although `ElementwiseKernel` does not work with 2d arrays, you are using 2d->1d transformation anyway, so nothing really stops you from writing

```
func = ElementwiseKernel(
    "pycuda::complex<float> *d, pycuda::complex<float> *x, pycuda::complex<float> *y",

    Template("""
    // Convert the linear index to subscripts:
    unsigned int a = i/${B};
    unsigned int b = i%${B};

    // Use the subscripts to access the array:
    //d[INDEX(a,b)] = x[INDEX(a,b)]+y[INDEX(a,b)];
    pycuda::complex<float> angle(0,arg(x[i]));
    pycuda::complex<float> module(abs(x[i]),0);
    d[i] = module * exp(angle);
    """).substitute(A=A, B=B),

    preamble=Template("""
    #define INDEX(a, b) a*${B}+b
    """).substitute(A=A, B=B))

func(d_gpu, x_gpu, y_gpu)
```

This way you will not need to juggle block/grid sizes because `PyCUDA` will handle this for you.